# Using fetchPolicy='cache-and-network' in useQuery in apollo-client not updating cache on fetchMore

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, graphql-js

I am using the `apollo-client` for my graphql setup. I have a paginated call for which i use the `fetchMore` function returned by the `useQuery` hook.
In the `fetchMore` function i was using its `updateQuery` param to append the new fetched data to  the results in the cache.

```
fetchMore({
  variables: {
    request: fetchMorerequest,
  },
  updateQuery: (previousResult, { fetchMoreResult }) => {
   const updatedResults = update(previousResult, {
      list: {
        data: { $push: fetchMoreResult.list.data },
        hasMore: { $set: fetchMoreResult.list.hasMore },
      },
    });

  return updatedResults;
  },
});
```

This was working fine for me.

Now, i have changed my `fetchPolicy` from the default `cache-first` to `cache-and-network`.
After that change the `updatedResults` that i am returning from my `updateQuery` function are being reflected in my cache, but not being returned in my component. i can see the updated items in my cache in the apollo extension in chrome. But not getting them in my component.

Any idea what can be an issue here? Am i missing something? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Set `nextFetchPolicy: 'cache-first'` in your `defaultOptions` or current query options.

[read more here](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/6907#issuecomment-682601465)